# Converting existing UIKit Core Data project to SwiftUI without losing saved data

Tags: xcode, swiftui, uikit

I currently have an existing UIKit project with Core Data functionality, and I'm looking to convert it to a SwiftUI project. While I don't mind opening a new project and rebuilding it from scratch, it's crucial for me to ensure that the data saved by the user is not lost during this process.

My main concern is how to guarantee that if I create a new SwiftUI project, the saved data will be preserved.

I want to ensure a smooth transition to SwiftUI without losing any user data.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions or recommendations!